# Scraper keeps on crawling identical links

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script in `python` in combination with `BeautifulSoup` to go on to the `next page` of a website using it's pagination button (there is a link connected to this button) until there is no new page to crawl. My script can crawl `next pages` using the pagination link. However, the problem is that the paginated links never end as the button (connected to next page link) doesn't gray out so I fall into an infinite loop. How can I get rid of that in such a way so that the script will check if I'm scraping two identical links cosecutively and as soon as it finds one it will break.

This is my script so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_content(link):
    while True:
        res = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

        #some code here to do the rest of the activity

        nextpage = soup.select_one(".roundright a")
        if not nextpage:break   #The loop doesn't break because the next page button never grayes out
        link = nextpage.get("href")
        print(link)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "http://www.viprealestateug.com/action/rentals/"
    get_content(url)
```

The results it produces:

```
http://www.viprealestateug.com/action/rentals/page/2/
http://www.viprealestateug.com/action/rentals/page/3/
http://www.viprealestateug.com/action/rentals/page/4/
http://www.viprealestateug.com/action/rentals/page/4/
http://www.viprealestateug.com/action/rentals/page/4/
and so on
```

I could have avoided such issues if I wished to go for any hardcoded approach but that is not what my intention is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just store the last link

```
    last_link = link
    link = nextpage.get("href")
    if link == last_link: break
    print(link)
```